# The custom token corresponds to a different audience

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using firebase for authentication on my app, while developing I created a firebase project which I was using for that purpose, but now I've to sync it with another app. So on updating my **google-services.json** I'm getting the below error and am not able to connect to firebase.

> The custom token corresponds to a different audience. [App ID does not match requested prject.]

How can I migrate my project to another one??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the app working, basically firebase does not allow two projects with similar configuration. So in my case the test project I created while development had SHA key of my app configured, becasue of which I was getting the error.

I deleted that key and the conflict got resolved.

This is mainly in cases when you're using modules like Authentication where SHA key is used to identify the app.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info? Where did you delete this key from?

Comment: I deleted this key from my firebase project settings.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on which key do you mean? I've found only one key that I can delete - in section Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging -> Project credentials, but it doesn't seem to be the right one

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the app data, it may be loading something from storage which is related to the other project.